# request Auth firebase storage js

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Hello I'm using firebase storage to store some images.

I've been using these access rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to create a "small barrier" so I'm using this

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to authenticate my requests

This worked before the change of rules

```
await storage.ref('images/' + id).put(image.data, {contentType: image.mimetype})
```

But now I can't do it so I've tried some things but it doesn't work

```
await storage.ref('images/' + id).put(image.data, {
    contentType: image.mimetype,
    auth: true
})
```

```
await storage.ref('images/' + id).put(image.data, {
    contentType: image.mimetype,
    auth: {
        uid: "",
        token: {
            sub: "",
            aud: "x",
            email: "",
            email_verified: false,
            phone_number: "",
            name: "",
            firebase: {
                sign_in_provider: "google.com"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```
await storage.ref('images/' + id).put(image.data, {
    contentType: image.mimetype,
    request: {
        auth: {
            uid: ""
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass anything to the request. The user must be logged in using Firebase Authentication. Firebase SDK will take care of authentication part for you. The security rules work only with Firebase Authentication, so make sure you are signed in with any of the providers.

You can find examples of registering new users or logging in existing one in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-version-8_2)